# Kali Linux wlan0 not detected

Tags: kali-linux

I have been having issues lately with my wireless on Kali 2 recently. It doesnt seem to pick up my built-in wireless card as wireless and instead detects it as eth0.  I understand this is a very common problem and most solutions i found was to get an external wireless adapter via usb. I got the ALFA AWUS036NHA with the Atheros AR9271 chip because it has been confirmed to work on Kali Linux. I just got it and I selected it as a Wireless Adapter and this one is being detected as eth1. I just wanted to know if there is any known solutions to this.

I am currently running windows 10 with Virtual Box running Kali Linux 2. I am running this on an Asus GL753VD Laptop and all of its usb ports are USB 3.0 and I know that Kali has issues with 3.0 but the adapter works so I dont know if that could be an issue.

Comment: If you look around on this site, there are quite a few people having trouble setting up drivers for Kali Linux. I recommend you switch the distribution, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) is why.

Comment: Kali 2 is obsolete and no longer supported. Try with kali 2017.3. You still have to configure Virtual Box to recognize your wifi interface.

Answer (score 0):

Between them, Windows and VirtualBox are abstracting away all the details of your network hardware (such as "it's wireless"), and are presenting Kali with a generic wired network connection (most likely, a virtual Intel Pro/1000 MT card).  That's one of the major purposes of virtualization: to provide the appearance of a computer that's consistent regardless of the actual hardware it's running on.

You may be able to use the specific functionality of your network adapter by uninstalling the Windows drivers for it, and instead using VirtualBox's USB settings to present it to Kali as a raw USB device.  Alternatively, you can bypass the whole issue by creating a LiveDVD or bootable USB drive and running Kali directly on your computer.